# Spring boot @TextIndexed not creating indexes in MongoDB

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application where I query the Mongodb using Mongo repositories. Everything working good as of now. But I wanted to add @TextIndexed on some fields. I added that, but spring is not creating any indexes on Mongodb. Here is the document class

```
@Indexed(unique = true)
@NotNull
private String name;

@TextIndexed
private String about;

@TextIndexed
private String information;

private String shortText;
```

Here is the service class method I used

```
List<SearchDto> searchResults = new ArrayList<>();
    TextCriteria textCriteria = TextCriteria.forDefaultLanguage()
            .matching(searchTerm);
    PageRequest page = PageRequest.of(0,4);
    List<Destination> destinations = destinationRepository.findAllBy(textCriteria, page);
```

When I create the index manually on mongodb, everything works good. If there is no index it ended up with exception

```
need exactly one text index for $text query
```

Any clues?

Comment: Check the collection. There's more than likely an existing text index defined on different fields. MongoDB won't create/use any more than one text index on a collection. If unsure then `dropIndexes()` on the collection and start the application again. It should create the **one** index on startup.

Comment: Yes, I have already checked that. There are no existing indexes on the collection at start up.

Comment: Try adding the index manually through the shell then. If there is a problem then you should see an error. Bottom line is that by the time your `findAllBy` is actually running, there is no valid index on the collection for the `$text` query to use.

Comment: I have already manually and it was working when I do that. But when I run the app it is not creating those indexes automatically!!

Comment: I found the issue. It is that I missed @ Document on my entities. And now everything is working fine. I was wondering that I didn't get any errors even though I missed @ Document and was working as expected until I used @ TextIndexed.

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/pull/845